# 403 Forbidden when using Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to webscrape a Website so I can gather some information for a project, here is my code and it's returning in the Console 403. I'm using request and cheerio to do this, why is this happening? Note I do know the what the majority of status codes mean.

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');


request('http://www.realmeye.com/forum/', function(err, resp, html) {
    if (!err) {
        const gatherInformation = cheerio.load(html);
        console.log(html);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a "User-Agent" header to the request, which fits for some browser (e.g. chrome). The server probably checks it to avoid unfamiliar clients.

A thumb rule for web scraping:
Use chrome dev tools / fiddler / other similar tool to inspect the request firing up from your client (chrome, firefox, etc') before trying to reproduce it on your framework (Inspect headers, cookies, etc').

The raw request I saw on Fiddler in your case (when hitting your url on chrome):

```
GET /forum/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.realmeye.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8
```

Most of servers would check "Accept" and "User-Agent" headers before returning 200 OK response.

The fixed code snippet:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

let options = {
    url: 'https://www.realmeye.com/forum/',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'
    }
};

request(options, function(err, resp, html) {
    if (!err) {
        const gatherInformation = cheerio.load(html);
        console.log(html);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to this and this really helped me.